# VB.net taking data from HTML form on click of a button

Tags: html, vb.net

So with my VB program I need to produce an HTML interface which allows users to insert comments (which will then be stored in an access database).

So far I've got the forms, but I have no actual clue what to do after:

```
classcontent.Write(<form action="comment_form.asp">Comment: <input type="text" name="comment"></input><br/><input type="submit" value="Submit"></input></form>)
```

So essentially on the click of the button I need the data inserted into the input to be stored then the page refreshed.

Any ideas?

Comment: your question is not cleared? You want to fill this form and press submit button automatically?

Comment: On the press of the button I want whatever is in the textbox to be stored in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your question completely but let me demonstrate you a complete example of submitting values to a web form.

```
Dim myusername As String = txtuser.Text
Dim mypassword As String = txtpass.Text
Dim mycomments As String = txtcomments.Text
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", myusername)
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", mypassword)
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("comment").SetAttribute("value", mycomments)
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")
```